# C# application terminates when writing data to excel worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to write data in excel work sheet using .Net. However, for some reason whole application terminates (No exception, no warning, no message)  when row counter increases to around 900. Whereas, there could be up to 10000 entries.

Furthermore it also terminates if i put a sleep statement, when filling contents. I suspect that there is some sort of timeout associated with excel objects?

Any Ideas what could be causing this? Thanks

Here is the main function -

```
    public void ProduceExcelReport(string reportDirPath, List<MedlineRecord> medlineRecords, List<AccessionRecord> accessionRecords,
        List<string> dataBanksOfInterest, bool overwrite)
    {
        Excell.Application excelApp = null;
        Excell.Workbooks excelWorkBooks = null;
        Excell.Workbook excelWorkBook = null;
        Excell.Sheets worksheets = null;
        Excell.Worksheet overAllWorkSheet = null;
        Excell.Worksheet parsingWorkSheet = null;
        Excell.Worksheet errorWorkSheet = null;
        Excell.Worksheet noCitationsSheet = null;
        Excell.Worksheet outOfScopeWorksheet = null;

        try
        {
            excelApp = new Excell.Application();
            string fullReportPath = Path.Combine(reportDirPath, ReportName);

            if (File.Exists(fullReportPath))
            {
                if (!overwrite)
                {
                    Logger.Warning(string.Format("File {0} already exists. Skipping report production." +
                                                 "You can change behaviour by editing OverwriteFilesWithNameConflict tag in settings",
                        fullReportPath));
                    return;
                }

                Logger.Warning(string.Format("File {0} already exists. Overwritting old report." +
                                             "You can change behaviour by editing OverwriteFilesWithNameConflict tag in settings",
                    fullReportPath));
            }

            // Initialise
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            excelWorkBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
            excelWorkBook = excelWorkBooks.Add(misValue);
            worksheets = excelWorkBook.Worksheets;
            overAllWorkSheet = (Excell.Worksheet) worksheets.Item[1];
            parsingWorkSheet = (Excell.Worksheet) worksheets.Item[2];
            errorWorkSheet = (Excell.Worksheet) worksheets.Item[3];
            noCitationsSheet = (Excell.Worksheet) worksheets.Add();
            outOfScopeWorksheet = (Excell.Worksheet)worksheets.Add();

            // Filling contents
            FillOverallReportContents(ref overAllWorkSheet, accessionRecords);
            FillMedlineParsingReportContents(ref parsingWorkSheet, medlineRecords, dataBanksOfInterest); // <- Terminates when writting contents
            FillErrorReportContents(ref errorWorkSheet, medlineRecords);
            FillNoCitationReportContents(ref noCitationsSheet, medlineRecords);
            FillOutOfScopeReportContents(ref outOfScopeWorksheet, medlineRecords, dataBanksOfInterest);

            excelWorkBook.SaveAs(fullReportPath);
            excelWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            excelApp.Quit(); // Quiting excel app
            Logger.Info(string.Format("Excel report at {0} was successfully created", fullReportPath));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.ExceptionError("Exception occured when trying to write Excel Report", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (overAllWorkSheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(overAllWorkSheet);
            if (parsingWorkSheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(parsingWorkSheet);
            if (noCitationsSheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(noCitationsSheet);
            if (errorWorkSheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(errorWorkSheet);
            if (outOfScopeWorksheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outOfScopeWorksheet);
            if (worksheets != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);
            if (excelWorkBook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkBook);
            if (excelWorkBooks != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkBooks);
            if (excelApp != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        }
    }
```

Here is one of the functions that fills worksheet contents

```
    private void FillMedlineParsingReportContents(ref Excell.Worksheet excelWorkSheet, List<MedlineRecord> medlineRecords, List<string> dataBanksOfInterest)
    {
        // Write the worksheet contents
        AddFirstRow(ref excelWorkSheet);
        excelWorkSheet.Name = "Medline XML Parsing Summary";
        excelWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6] = string.Format("Total articles: {0}", medlineRecords.Count);
        excelWorkSheet.Cells[3, 6] = string.Format("Total number dataBank list tags: {0}", (from element in medlineRecords 
                                                                                            where element.DataBanksDict.Count > 0
                                                                                            select element).Count());
        excelWorkSheet.Cells[4, 6] = string.Format("Total number dataBank tags: {0}", (from element in medlineRecords
                                                                                       select element.DataBanksDict.Count).Sum());
        excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, 6] = string.Format("Total number accession tags: {0}",  (from element in medlineRecords
                                                                                       select element.GetAccessionRecords().Count).Sum());
        int i = 2;
        foreach (MedlineRecord record in Utilities.FilterOutMedlineRecords(medlineRecords, dataBanksOfInterest))
        {
            foreach (AccessionRecord accessionRecord in record.GetAccessionRecords())
            {
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = accessionRecord.BankName;
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = accessionRecord.AccessionId;
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = accessionRecord.PMID;
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = accessionRecord.FileName;
                i++;

                // Terminates when I reaches around 800-900
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And does the "Exception occured when trying to write Excel Report"-Log-entry show up in your log?

Comment: No nothing. Events that should be triggered on termination are not called as well.

Comment: I also noticed that if I put sleep statement at some point when filling the contents. Application still terminates even if i is < 800. Thus I presume there is some sort of time out associated with excel, which causes termination?

Comment: Those `ref` parameters don't look right. Are you exchanging the objects in those methods?

Comment: tried removing them but behavior is still the same.